# Insert only populated fields into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to insert only populated ID fields to MySQL, meaning if two out of three are populated, only two to be inserted. I got blind with many code lines, and can't see where Im making a mistake.

Logic is that I'll search for the serial number, once selected it will populate row ID from the serial number into the ID field.
I want to pass ID field value to the database. However, below code is submitting all ID fields even the empty ones (where serial number is not selected), and I dont need to pass records for not populated ID field.
Where am I making a mistake?

Thanks

```js
$idCount = count($_POST['assetsn_id']);
echo $idCount;
for($i=0; $i < $idCount; ++$i) {
    $assetsn_id = $_POST['assetsn_id'][$i];
    $assetsn_location_address = $_POST['assetsn_location_address'];
    $assetsn_location_rack = $_POST['assetsn_location_rack'];
    $assetsn_location_shelf = $_POST['assetsn_location_shelf'];
    $assetsn_location_bin = $_POST['assetsn_location_bin'];
    $assetsn_location_createdby = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $assetsn_location_userlogid = $_SESSION['user']['userlogid'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO asset_serial_locations SET assetsn_id=?, assetsn_location_address=?, assetsn_location_rack=?, assetsn_location_shelf=?, assetsn_location_bin=?, assetsn_location_createdby=?, assetsn_location_userlogid=?";
$result = modifyRecord($sql, 'sssssss', [$assetsn_id, $assetsn_location_address, $assetsn_location_rack, $assetsn_location_shelf, $assetsn_location_bin, $assetsn_location_createdby, $assetsn_location_userlogid]);
    
if ($result) {
    $_SESSION['success_msg'] = "Location updated successfully!";
    header("location: " . BASE_URL . "workshop/location/");
    exit(0);
} else {
    $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Something went wrong. Could not update locations.".'<br />'.mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
```

```html
Serial number #1
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="search" name="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search for serial number..." />
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="assetsn_id[]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ID" /><br /><br />
Serial number #2
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="search" name="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search for serial number..." />
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="assetsn_id[]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ID" /><br /><br />
Serial number #3
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="search" name="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search for serial number..." />
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="assetsn_id[]" autocomplete="off" placeholder="ID" />
```

Comment: I'd assume you'd just test `$assetsn_id` for empty or null or similar and `continue` then?

Comment: I've tried with isset, empty, null, and nothing really helped. Please note that ID field gets populated through the script and backend php file which reads ID based on selected Serial number. I dont think those codes are relevant here, as they work fine for reading. Submitting only populated ID fields doesn't work, it submits two with ID and then one blank ID field.

Comment: A bug could be in this code: $idCount = count($_POST['assetsn_id']); as count represents number of ID fields, regardless of if it is populated or not.
If I could count only populated fields, that would resolve the problem.

Comment: You'll probably need to `var_dump()` the contents then, maybe an errant space is in there: https://3v4l.org/fAtnq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_filter` to remove nulls values from an array :

```
$_POST['assetsn_id'] = array_filter($_POST['assetsn_id']);
$idCount = count($_POST['assetsn_id']);
echo $idCount;
for($i=0; $i < $idCount; ++$i) {
....
}
```

Here what `array_filter`  can remove :

```
$a = array(0, '0', NULL, FALSE, '', array());
var_dump(array_filter($a));
// array()
```